# More elegant way to toggle a CSS class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tasked with some coding stuff again and as I am getting more and more safe in this I want to be more elegant as well. Here I have some code to toggle a class on click and then toggle it back on click.

Is there a way to do this with a little less code?

```
function openNav() {
  $opener = $('.topNavigation.closed .topNavOpener');
  $closer = $('.topNavigation.open .topNavOpener');
  $topNavigation = $('.topNavigation');

  $opener.click(function() {
    $topNavigation.removeClass('closed');
    $topNavigation.addClass('open');
    openNav();
  });

  $closer.click(function() {
    $topNavigation.addClass('closed');
    $topNavigation.removeClass('open');
    openNav();
  });
}
```

Comment: one way to simplify things would be to change the css so that one class is applied by default (for example, default is closed) so you only have to toggle open on and off.

Comment: Well you should at least fix the code so that each "click" does not re-bind the event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it closed or open as default, than create a class for the other, and toggle that class

Create a toggle button:

```
$("#toggleButton").click(function(){
    $topNavigation.toggleClass('classNameHere');
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function openNav() {
  $('.topNavigation .topNavOpener').click(function() {
    $('.topNavigation').toggleClass('open');
    openNav();
  });
}
```